# QML - XMLHttpRequest User-Agent change

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, qml

I'm trying to change User-Agent used by XMLHttpRequest.
This is my connect() function.

It works perfectly but User-Agent isn't being changed..
Someone knows why? (I've checked headers with Fiddler) :(

```
function connect() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.HEADERS_RECEIVED) {
        console.log('Trying to connect...')
    } else if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        console.log('DONE')
    }
}
  xhr.open("GET", "http://www.mywebsite/index.php?waddawda");
  xhr.setRequestHeader('User-Agent','FAKE-USER-AGENT');
  xhr.send();
}
```

Thanks for your help.

P.S. If it's not possible to do it with XMLHttpRequest please suggest me an alternative :) I need to do a GET request with a modified User-Agent.

Comment: This won't work in most browsers that adhere to specifications.

Comment: It looks that `User-Agent` is hardcoded inside `Qt` libs and not changable. I've tried several ways to change it and is always `Mozilla 5/0` for me. I think it's bug and you have to sent it to bugreport

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work, because back then, setting the user agent was forbidden by specification. Nowadays it should work, because it has been [allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name). It works in Firefox.

In some browsers (Chrome) it still (2023-02) doesn't work because of a [long standing bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=571722).